# Reading JCasC bitbucket repoOwner and repository from a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jcasc

For reasons that are beyond my control, I need a Jenkinsfile that can be used in 2 jobs without modification. Each will need to know it's repoOwner & repository for using the correct location to store it's reports in a bucket. At present these values are hard coded and are the only differences between my two files. I understand that I can read the GIT_URL and derive these values, but is it possible to read the branchSources from my multibranchPipelineJob from within my Jenkinsfile instead?